# Connect IP camera to raspberry pi ethernet port

Tags: pi-3, camera, static-ip

I'm working on a project that will involve connecting an IP camera to the Raspberry i through the Ethernet port and then send that image through the HDMI port to a monitor.

I was thinking a IP camera would be the best option because the Raspberry Pi will be about 100 ft away from the camera. I've been searching online to make sure that this is possible before I buy anything but I can't seem to find any sure answer. The answers I find talk about going through the internet but for this project there will be no internet available.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are connecting this Raspberry Pi directly to the camera, then you will need to give the Raspberry Pi a static address in the same subnet as the camera since the camera itself almost certainly will not be offering DHCP addresses to its network peer. Then...

## 1:

Install a desktop application called VLC,

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install vlc
```

Then open the network stream via the VLC menu, however, depending on the camera, this might not give a satisfactory result, so instead...

## 2:

Use a command line application called omxplayer:

```
omxplayer -o hdmi http://cameraaddr:port/path
```

or if your camera streams using rtsp protocol:

```
omxplayer -o hdmi rtsp://cameraaddr:port/path
```

Either way, you will need to determine the exact protocol, address, and path for your network camera as brands may differ, for example, a Ubiqiti network camera can be configured to stream with an address like this:

```
rtsp://10.0.5.90:554/s0
```

If you need the Raspberry Pi to automatically open the stream when it boots, it may be possible to turn the omxplayer command into an init.d script.

Comment: I'm assuming that if a mic is on the camera it will transfer audio as well to the pi to then be output on a tv?

Comment: If your IP camera supports audio and video in the same stream, VLC should be able to handle it. omxplayer might need extra software and configuration to support audio. Also, both might default to sending audio via the 3.5mm jack instead of via HDMI, so if that is an issue, it might be extra work to change to HDMI audio. It really depends on the camera and its protocols.

Comment: So I finally got the camera. I have it connected to my pi and ran hostname -I and I can see both the ip address of the pi and the camera. What does it mean to set a static ip address in the same subnet as the camera? and then when I open vlc network stream do I just put http//:camera_ip_address_here ?

Comment: Depending on the camera, it will likely come with a default address, like http://192.168.1.1 for example. Some cameras might immediately try to pick up an automatic DHCP address from your network. Either way, most cameras will have a configuration page that you can access at the cameras address. From there, you should be able to set a static private address, like 10.0.0.3 or 192.168.1.3, for example. The Raspberry Pi should then be configured with a static address in the same subnet as the address the camera was set to.

Comment: So if you set the camera to 10.0.0.3, then you should set the Rasperry Pi to 10.0.0.2 or 10.0.0.4. Regarding what streaming address to enter in VLC, it depends on the camera. It might stream using http protocol or it might stream using rtsp protocol. You also might need to enter a path after the protocol and address. It all depends on the camera.